# I want to display <!DOCTYPE html> on my site as a string

Tags: php, html

`<!DOCTYPE html>` is not displaying on my site, I have a simple website containing html and php question. When I render questions from database,  `<!DOCTYPE html>` will display as it is in input or textarea but without using input field it will show nothing.

This is the question not displaying html code:
[image]

Here I have added   in statement:

[image]

Comment: `htmlspecialchars`

Comment: Please learn to do some basic research yourself … typing something trivial like “how do i display html as text on my site” into Google could have led you to that duplicate right away.

Comment: <span><</span><span>!DOCTYPE html</span><span>></span>

Answer (score 2):

Use `htmlspecialchars` or `htmlentities` before outputting your data from the database.

```
<?php echo htmlspecialchars($string); ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo htmlentities($string); ?>
```

**Reference**

[PHP Manual - htmlentities](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php)
[PHP Manual - htmlspecialchars](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php)

Answer (score 0):

Encode your content before outputting:

```
<?= htmlspecialchars($questionContent); ?>
```